# Custom File Format to partition data while writing

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I want to save my spark dataframe to a file with custom file format,
such that it partitions data to different files while writing to the file.
Also I need single part file for each partition key.

I have tried extending TextBasedFileFormat and change writer to suit my needs.
The data is getting partitioned while writing to file without shuffle.
But I feel each rdd partition will write data to different part file

Comment: `repartition` and then `partitionBy` as in `df.repartition("partitionKey").write.partitionBy("partitionKey").csv("filepath")` should eliminate the problem of each rdd writing to a different part file for each partition. Not sure about extending the file format though. Why does it have to be a custom file format?

Comment: @Gsquare If I repartition a shuffle operation will happen. I need a custom file format because I want to write the fields in different lines and hence the type of records in every line will be different it will not be a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the dataframe, each partition of underlying RDD will be written by separate tasks. Now each of these RDD partitions might correspond to data which belongs to different partition key. So each task will end up creating multiple part files.

To solve this, you have to repartition your dataframe by the partitionKey. This will involve a shuffle and all the data corresponding to same partitionKey will come into same RDD partition. This can be done by -

```
val newDf = df.repartition("partitionKey")
```

Now this RDD can be written to any file format (say parquet, csv etc) and their should be 1 file per partition. If the file size is going big, it might create multiple files. This can be controlled by config "spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile".

```
val newDf = df.repartition("partitionKey")
newDf.write.partitionBy("partitionKey").parquet("<directory_path>")
```